# Why addAll(Collection<? extends E>) is used to put elements in a collection while wildcard extends is generally suggested for Get?

Tags: java, generics, extends

I get the point that “? extends E” means is that it is ok to add all
members of a collection with elements of any type that is a subtype of E. 
Hence for a List , addAll(all values of List) will hold good. 
But then why it is generalised that "Use an extends wildcard when you only get values out of a structure" as per The Get and Put Principle ?

Comment: It has already been discussed thousands of times, e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

Comment: *“? extends E” means is that it is ok to add all members of a collection with elements of any type that is a subtype of E.* No, it doesn’t.  It means it accepts elements of a specific subtype which may be E or may be a descendant of E.  You cannot add Integers or Doubles to a `Collection<? extends Number>`, because it *might* be a `Collection<Integer>` or it *might* be a `Collection<Double>` or it might be a `Collection<BigDecimal>`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `addAll` from the parameter `Collection`, you're "getting" all the elements in the `Collection` parameter and adding them to another collection. Therefore "Producer Extends (Consumer Super)" still applies here.

By enforcing the generic `<? extends E>`, we are ensuring that all elements in the parameter are `instanceof E`, and can therefore be successfully added to a `Collection<E>`.

Comment: See also example source code for [`addAll`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) which could also elucidate the point.